# Non-trivial zero divisors of Polynomial Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm writing below some things i found in an exercise:

Let $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1 $ and $B:=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$

Since the degree of $f(x)$ is $3$ and I found an evident root $f(1)=0$, then $f(x)$ is reducible. So, I can say that $A$ is not a field. Furthermore, considering $[x^2+1]\in A$, since $GCD([x^2+1],f(x)) \neq1 $ then $[x^2+1] \notin \mathscr{U}(A)$ so must be in $\mathscr{D}(A)$.

So, assuming that what i said it's right, my question is:
***what should I multiply $[x^2+1]$ to get $0$ ?***

Comment: Multiply it by something to get a polynomial that has a factor of $x^3+x^2+x+1$. By just guessing, $x+1$ works. Or, use division like the answer below suggests (division is a better method in general).

Comment: $((\color{#c00}{x^4\!-\!1})/(x\!-\!1))/(\color{#c00}{x^2+1}) = (\color{#c00}{x^2\!-\!1})/(x\!-\!1) = x\!+\!1\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Just divide $x^2+1$ into $x^3+x^2+x+1$. This gives

$x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+1)(x+1)$ with no remainder.